# Routing a simple search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm trying to create a simple search form that passes users off to a separate 'results' page.

My view for index.html.erb is below:

```
<%= simple_form_for results_path, method: :get, html: { class: "form-inline justify-content-center" } do |f| %>

    <%= f.select :what, options_for_select([['Happy Hours Anywhere','Anywhere'],['After Work Drinks','After Work Drinks'],['Somewhere to Relax with Friends', 'Relaxing with Friends'], ['A Club Night','Club Night'], ['Somewhere for Date Night','Date Night'], ['A Place to Watch Sports', 'Watching Sports']]),{} ,:class => "form-control select-box font-lightweight"  %>

    <%= f.select :datetime, options_for_select(dates_for_search_select.each_with_index.map{|d, i| [d[1],d[0]]}), {}, :class => "form-control select-box font-lightweight" %>

    <%= f.select :time, options_for_select(times_for_search_select.each_with_index.map{|d, i| [d[1],d[0]]}), {}, :class => "form-control select-box font-lightweight" %>

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Discover', :class => 'btn btn-block btn-danger btn-embossed top-margin ' %>
<%end%>
```

I've created my 'results' route, which can be seen below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :offers
  resources :venues
    get 'home/results' => 'home#results', :as => :results
    get 'home/index'
  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"    
end
```

However when I generate the HTML the resulting form the action keeps routing back to the index page:

```
<form class="simple_form form-inline justify-content-center" novalidate="novalidate" 
 action="/home/index" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">

</form>
```

What am i missing?

Comment: try with this   get "results", to: "home#results"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simple_form_for` asks for an object as first argument (class instance or symbol). then you can add `url: articles_path`, as you would for a normal `form_for`. See [simple form source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/c3a307cb9501208e053f771738e34a3d93d33858/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb)

So you need to have a line something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for :results, url: results_path, method: :get, html: { class: "form-inline justify-content-center" } do |f| %>
```